# Changing drupal $base_path

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

I am trying to install a drupal 7 module. It says that I have to change the $base_path if the site is not root. I have installed my drupal site at /localhost/drupal7/ on my local machine. Can someone tell me what should I change my $base_path to?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your base path would be the path Drupal is installed in. In your case `/localhost/drupal7/`.

What I like to do is just create a new entry in my hosts file:

```
# C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts

# Add this line
127.0.0.1 Localhost2
```

And then for each extra website add in httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName Localhost2
   DocumentRoot "c:/path/to/folder/Localhost2"
</VirtualHost>
```

This would be if you are on Windows anyways.